# My bittorrent client doesn't load by default

Tags: transmission

I have upgraded from 10.10 to 12.10. When I click a torrent link, it asks what I want to use, but I'm not sure where the application is actually located. Before it would just load Transmission by default. Any ideas about what to do?

Comment: Try saving the file, and then right click-->open with, and choose Transmission.

Answer (score 0):

The Transmission binary (or link to the binary) is probably located in `/usr/bin` with the name `transmission-gtk`.

Answer (score -1):

By default, applications which start at session login time, can be managed by the following menu entry : **Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications**.  (Menu >  Preference > Application au démarrage in french).

So, you may want to put back the bittorent client into this list.  You only have to know that the command for launching the Transmission Bitorrent client minimised is "**transmission-gtk -m**" (without the quotes and with the space).  The two other fields "name" and "comment" will not change the behavior of Ubuntu but certainly help you.

The command for launching application may be found in the "edit menu" program.  It edits the desktops files, which is have a bit of complexity but this is an other story.

So, as a conclusion, type in your ubuntu program seach text box "Startup Applications", run the program and let you be guided by the graphical interface.

Comment: Yes it does, go to you preferences menu and try to add a new line for your transmission client.

Comment: Well, Could you explain how?

Comment: Sorry, I had no enough time to answer with this full length answer...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. He wants Transmission to open torrent files automatically, presumably from the browser.

Comment: Yes, the question seems unclear, bittoreent client is not loading means, it does not launch.  Bittorent links cannot be loaded is an other story...

Comment: I don't agree :) You don't need to have the bittorrent client running in the background to open torrent files or links (which is what your answer is about).

Comment: Yes, but torrents do not load if transmission is not launched => question unclear => not targeted answer.